# The disk drive for /mnt/sdc is not ready yet or not present

Tags: automount

After adding a new hard disk to my computer I always get this error on startup:

[image]

I tried to disable automount options with `disks` and `kcmshell4` but the problem persists.

How can I solve it?

**edit:**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

#Entry for /dev/sda2 :
UUID=da7f24b9-5ae6-47f5-bbaf-07094c5dc9cd   /   ext4    defaults    0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=721C5DCC6CF6D822   /media/H    ntfs-3g defaults,users,locale=en_US.UTF-8   0   0


/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Ut165_USB2FlashStorage_000000000005C8-0:0 /mnt/usb-Ut165_USB2FlashStorage_000000000005C8-100:0 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/sdc /mnt/sdc auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-udisks-auth 0 0
```

Comment: What is in your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: @arsaKasra:  fstab contents added.

Comment: How about commenting out the last line?